# Internet doesn't work on Wifi but works via Ethernet on laptop

Tags: internet, wireless-router, ethernet, dhcp, gigabit-ethernet

Internet doesn't work on Any Wifi connected by Ethernet cable but if same cable is connected to Laptop I get internet connection.

#### Here is the detailed explanation.

- I have one TPLink Router (Main), I use it as parent router. All the
  devices connected to main router wirelessly have internet access.
- I have I-ball router (I-Ball) connected to main router via LAN port
  of I-Ball. Internet doesn't work in this device.
- When I use same cable which was as input for I-Ball router and
  connect it to my MacBook it shows internet connectivity.

#### What I Tried.

1. Set I-Ball router network mode to DHCP.
2. copied the IP information of MacBook to I-Ball Router as Static IP

Both of the above steps doesn't work independently.

#### What my conclusion is

- The LAN ports of TPLink Wi-Fi is 10/100/1000 Mbps
- The I-Ball Router
  WAN port is 10/100 Mbps,
- The MacBook supports network with
  10/100/1000 Mbps.

I think this is the issue, do I need to change
either of router?

Can you please guide me if I am correct, or there seems to be some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 2 Windows 11 Pro laptops and wireless on both works well.  Wireless also worked well on Windows 10 when I had that.

Update BIOS (UEFI), Power Management driver and Wireless drivers.  In fact use the Dell Updater App to do this.

Do a final restart and test.

When all the above has been done, if you still have wireless issues, then get a USB Wireless adapter with Windows 11 drivers and try that.

If the USB adapter works, the wireless card may have a hardware issue.

Answer (score -1):

So after trying various approaches like setting up static ip, checking with different routers, turns out, the ethernet cable was bit by a rat. the rat bit only 1 out of 4 data wires, hence I was able to connect to internet directly via MacBook but not through the router.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).